# Replacing parameter values in URLs

Tags: php, regex

```
// Below are a number of strings which need ammending
$string = "www.development_test.php?action=show_development_crs&test1&test2";
$string = "www.development_test.php?action=show_rfw&test1";
$string = "www.development_test.php?action=show_development_crs";
```

I need to write a `preg_replace()` function which replace the value between "`=`" + "`&`" or in the case of the bottom string everything after "=" when & doesnt exist with "newAction"..

Does anyone have any ideas?

This is what I have tried so far, but failed:

```
public function test1()
{
    $action      = "newAction";
    $string      = "www.development_crs.php?action=show_development_crs&test1&test2";
    $pattern     = '/(action=)(.*)(&)/';
    $replacement = "action=$action&";

    $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

    echo $string;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of the functionality you desire?

Answer (score 6):

```
$action      = 'newAction';
$string      = 'www.development_crs.php?action=show_development_crs&test1&test2';
$pattern     = '/action=[^&]+(.*)/';
$replacement = "action=$action$1";

$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
www.development_crs.php?action=newAction&test1&test2
```

Answer (score 3):

try the pattern below

```
$pattern='/action=([a-z0-9_\-%]+)&/';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern     = '/action=.*?(&|$)/';
$replacement = "action=$action$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems with your pattern. Not that I'm a regex expert however,

Try something like this:

/action=[^&]+/

or

/action=[^&]*/

This will match 'action=' and then the rest of the string until it encounters a &. The + means that it must have at least one character between the = and the & to accept the string.

Hope this helps :)